# NPM ERR! exit status code 77 when using "npm start"

Tags: npm, electron

I receive an error when using "npm start" it throws me this error.

I've already tried npm-cache-clean , and also trying delete the node_modules as well as deleting the package-lock.json , followed by "npm install" this didn't yield a different result.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 77
npm ERR! crimstock@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 77
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the crimstock@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Negus\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-23T04_45_49_315Z-debug.log
```

```
 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~prestart: crimstock@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: crimstock@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Desktop\Crimstock2\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Negus\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Negus\Desktop\Code\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Negus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\Negus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Phantom\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin;C:\Users\Negus\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Negus\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Mongodb\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
9 verbose lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\Desktop\Crimstock2
10 silly lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 77  signal: null
12 info lifecycle crimstock@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: crimstock@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 77
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid crimstock@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Desktop\Crimstock2
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v8.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 77
22 error crimstock@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
22 error Exit status 77
23 error Failed at the crimstock@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 77, true ]
```

I want the electron app to start and not throw and error because I can't test any javascript in the index.js file I have

Comment: can you try starting electron without your project ? add this script and run it `"brokentest": "electron"` (without the dot)

Error 77 normally only occurs with native packages

Comment: I added that to the script and still the same error , Do i leave "start": "electron ." in the scripts as well ?

Comment: Yeah this was just to test if you scripts or electron itself has the issue. And this just tells me that electron itself is the culprit.

Could you do the following. Delete the node_modules folder, Delete any .lock file in your project root. Run `npm i` or `yarn` depending on what you use, then try the start and brokentest again.

Comment: Okay , so i did the following and when i ran npm i to reinstall all dependencies this error showed up   
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 77
npm ERR! electron@4.1.4 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 77
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@4.1.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: Okay, this is one step closer :) Can you try the following, run the script from a command line with administrator rights. And also run `npm i --verbose` for more details on why that script crashes

Comment: Okay , I ran the script  it completed successfully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192275/discussion-between-ksuby-and-hans-koch).

Comment: Great so everything is resolved now? Should i create a awnser with a proper explainaintion why so you can mark it as correct ? :)